# Trouble printing result in another sub procedure

Tags: excel, vba, function, web-scraping

I've created a macro to parse some links and their concerning texts from a webpage. When I print the result in within `fetchData()`, I get them all. But, when I print the result in `printResult()`, I get very few of them.

***How can I print all the result in another sub, as in `printResult()`?***

```
Sub fetchData()
    Const baseUrl = "https://www.psacard.com"
    Const link = "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, nUrl$, sName$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each posts In Html.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If posts.getElementsByTagName("a").Length Then
            nUrl = baseUrl & Split(posts.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
            sName = posts.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
            printResult nUrl, sName
        End If
    Next posts
End Sub

Sub printResult(ByVal nUrl As String, ByVal sName As String)
    Debug.Print nUrl, sName
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything looks ok to me. You may see some entries missing becuase you are using `Debug` which prints to Immediate Window and the window has a limit to the text it can display. Try writing it to an excel sheet and then check if you are still missing data?

Comment: Yes, I got everything when i wrote them to an excel sheet. I was not aware of this invaluable information `immediate window has a limit to the text it can display` @Siddharth Rout. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: Yes it has a limit of (if I am not wrong) 199 lines...

Comment: Also, the watches/locals windows have a limited length for strings they will display. And some Excel-Functions are limited to 255 Characters, some more research can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516702/getting-around-the-max-string-size-in-a-vba-function