# Excel VBA: Compare one "column" or "row" of a multi-dimensional array with another one

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, comparison

I am trying to compare one "column" of an array with another, without having to make loops checking through the columns in entirity...

I have found something that works for arrays of a specific format ("code-1") *:

```vb
For intColumn = 2 To intNumOfColumns
If Join(arrArrayToChecK(intColumn), ":-^") = Join(arrArrayToChecK(intColumn - 1), ":-^") Then
etc.
```

But then every "dimension" or "column" in the array has to be formatted by (x)(y) and not (x,y) as seen in the following snippets:

Screen snippet of array that works in code:
[image]

Screen snippet of array that don't work in code:
[image]

For the first array, each dimension/column may vary in size. Meanwhile, the second array has "quadratic dimensions", i.e. every column/dimension of the array has the same amount of rows. **Question 1 (q-1)**: Can anyone help me get a similar code that works for the latter case?

**Another related question (q-2) is**: If I wanted to rather compare the "rows" of an array (let's say by the format that "works"), would there be a similar way? I know I can build the arrays different from the start, making rows into columns, etc. but I hope to not have "almost-duplicate" code for this variant of the problem...

As can be seen here, If I try to transpose the array, it can no longer be joined (error-message pops up). - The format is now the (x,y) also here , equal to the issue in q-1. So  probably, in order to answer q-2, q-1 needs to be answered first...

[image]

'* The delimiter is random ":-^". 
I.e. it is never supposed to appear in any list this code is used on ever (I am making this code snippet as part of my "useful" VBA-functions library so that it can be used in later instances too, not only for this specific project).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a function that would return a boolean indicating whether two 1D arrays (in a jagged array or not!?) or two columns of a 2D array are equal. Although I can't see any particular use for such a function, I would suggest you create one for the 1D array and two (one for rows and one for columns) for the 2D array. To make them useful in more cases, you should use loops since you will loop only until the first different element. Even if this first element is never found, the code should be more efficient than using `Join` to compare two strings.

Comment: Then there is the limitation of the size of a string and of the `Transpose` function to consider. All in all,  the `Join` idea may be kind of useful when you want to compare the arrays on the fly and your useful functions aren't at your side. Surely you are aware that shorter code often comes with some limitations and need not be more efficient.

Comment: _... without having to make loops ..._ Why is that?  If you are assuming loops will be slow, in my experience loops often (usually) out perform shorter "smarter" code

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. 1 - It is to check in a range if the pattern above/below is consistent - or it was for checking for duplicates, I do not remember on the fly now. 
But if my code worked "allround" I could use it in later instances too for similar tasks with arrays. 

Yes, I was not sure if the if the join-code is truly faster, but it has been very fast this far. 
The limitation of string-format should not be a problem, ref. Kevin Brock: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516702/getting-around-the-max-string-size-in-a-vba-function

Answer (score 2):

### Are Two Columns of a 2D Array Equal?

[image]

**An Example (The Calling Procedure)**

```vb
Sub AreTwoColumnsEqualTest()
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Table Range
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = trg.Columns.Count
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = trg.Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = trg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' Data Range
    
    ' Write the values from the data range to an array.
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = drg.Value
    
    ' Use the 'AreTwoColumnsEqual' function and print which columns are equal,
    ' and which are not
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To cCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To cCount
            If AreTwoColumnsEqual(Data, i, j) Then
                Debug.Print "Columns " & i & " and " & j & " are equal."
            Else
                Debug.Print "Columns " & i & " and " & j & " are not equal."
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

**The (Useful) Function**

```vb
Function AreTwoColumnsEqual( _
    Data() As Variant, _
    ByVal Column1 As Long, _
    ByVal Column2 As Long, _
    Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim CompareMethod As Long: CompareMethod = CLng(MatchCase) + 1
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        If StrComp(CStr(Data(r, Column1)), CStr(Data(r, Column2)), _
                CompareMethod) <> 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
    
    AreTwoColumnsEqual = True

End Function
```

**The Result**

```
Columns 1 and 2 are not equal.
Columns 1 and 3 are not equal.
Columns 1 and 4 are not equal.
Columns 1 and 5 are equal.
Columns 2 and 3 are not equal.
Columns 2 and 4 are equal.
Columns 2 and 5 are not equal.
Columns 3 and 4 are not equal.
Columns 3 and 5 are not equal.
Columns 4 and 5 are not equal.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I will have try to incorporate in my old code :) But I will not "close the thread" as I guess others also could be looking for an answer to: how to change the format of arrays: (x)(y) and not (x,y) by some "simpler"/"more compact code", or -by potentially specifying something at the beginning of the procedures, etc. Again thanks for the help.