# Checkbox on web page using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, web-scraping, html

I am trying to check a checkbox on a web page using Excel VBA. My code did not work. (There was no error but the tick was ticked)

How can I make the tick show when I do it on the web page?

Am I doing something wrong with the web scraping?

---

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="slick-header ui-state-default">
  <div class="slick-header-columns ui-sortable" style="left: -1000px;" unselectable="on">
    <div title="Sélectionner / désélectionner tout" class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473vssGrid_rowSelect_123527" style="width: 21px;">
      <div class="header">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473purchase_order" style="width: 104px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Bon de commande</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473purchase_order_date" style="width: 104px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Date de la commande</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator slick-sort-indicator-asc"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473latest_ship_date" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Date d'expédition maximale</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473vendor_code" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Vendor code</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473payee_code" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Code bénéficiaire</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473warehouse_id" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Entrepôt de destination</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473currency_code" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Devise</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
      <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_951473status" style="width: 103px;">
      <div class="header slick-sort-header"><span class="slick-column-name">Statut</span></div><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**VBA code :**

```
Sub automationAmazon()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "link"

        Do While .busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

    Set Email = ie.document.getelementbyid("ap_email")
    Email.Value = "email@exemple.com"

    Set Password = ie.document.getelementbyid("ap_password")
    Password.Value = "xxx"

    Set submit = ie.document.getelementbyid("signInSubmit")
    submit.Click

    With ie
        .navigate "link"
        Do While .busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

    ie.document.all("searchBy").Value = "PURCHASE_ORDER"
    ie.document.all("purchaseOrderNumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2).Text
    ie.document.getelementbyid("create-invoice-search-submit").Click

    Dim cBox As Object
    Set cBox = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("header")(0)
    cBox.Click
End Sub
```

---

The HTML:

[image: HTML]

---

Comment: I am sorry biut it is a link for an intranet.I can share with you source page if this helps

Comment: I tried to put all the info :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are after is inside an iframe which is inside a form. You have to negotiate them. I have read your html in from a file.

The bit you need is:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).document.getElementsByTagName("input")(4).Click
```

---

Form and iframe:

[image]

---

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFS As Object, sText As String
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\doc.html")

    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        sText = oFS.ReadAll()
    Loop

    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, b As Object
    html.body.innerHTML = sText
    Set b = html.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).document.getElementsByTagName("input")(4)
    Debug.Print b.outerHTML
    b.Click
End Sub
```

---

**Verifying correct element:**

The printout to the immediate window of the selected element's outerHTML shows that the correct element is selected:

[image: output]

---

### Ensuring pages load each after each click

Use

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

after each click event to allow the page to load. That includes after the clicks you do in the login sequence before attempting this click.

---

Reading in HTML file script adapted from [ozknows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18286666/6241235).

Comment: error 404 - object required \ here I am not able to share whole HTML source due to a ristrictions , there is a possibility to send it to you via email ?

Comment: try this link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AGtksv-p7YkykBufrz814Zdoo8-wRUyV

Comment: hereby link with source 2 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AGtksv-p7YkykBufrz814Zdoo8-wRUyV